# Optional dependencies in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, optional-parameters

I'm trying to implement a controller in AngularJS which is used across multiple pages. It makes use of some services. Some of them are loaded on all pages, some - not. I mean it is defined in different files, and these files are loaded independently. But if I do not load these services on all pages I got error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: firstOtionalServiceProvider <- firstOtionalService
```

So, I need to load scripts on all pages. Can I declare dependency as optional in Angular? E.g:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'firstRequiredService', 'secondRequiredService', 'optional:firstOptionalService', 'optional:secondOptionalService', function($scope, firstRequiredService, secondRequiredService, firstOptionalService, secondOptionalSerivce){

    // No need to check, as firstRequiredService must not be null
    firstRequiredService.alwaysDefined();

    // If the dependency is not resolved i want Angular to set null as argument and check
    if (firstOptionalService) {
        firstOptionalService.mayBeUndefinedSoCheckNull();
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No, Angular does not yet support optional dependencies out of the box. You'd better put all your dependencies into a module and load it as one Javascript file. If you need another set of dependencies - consider creating another module in another JS and putting all common dependencies to common JS.

However, behavior you've described can be achieved with [`$injector` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$injector). You simply inject `$injector` instead of all your dependencies to a controller and pull dependencies from it manually, checking if they exist. That's it:

*index.html:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="1.js"></script>
    <script src="2.js"></script>
    <title>1</title>
  </head>
  <body data-ng-controller="DemoController">
  </body>
</html>
```

*app.js:*

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('commonService', function(){
    this.action = function(){
        console.log('Common service is loaded');
    }
});

myApp.controller('DemoController', ['$scope', '$injector', function($scope, $injector){
    var common;
    var first;
    var second;

    try{
        common = $injector.get('commonService');
        console.log('Injector has common service!');
    }catch(e){
        console.log('Injector does not have common service!');
    }
    try{
        first = $injector.get('firstService');
        console.log('Injector has first service!');
    }catch(e){
        console.log('Injector does not have first service!');
    }
    try{
        second = $injector.get('secondService');
        console.log('Injector has second service!');
    }catch(e){
        console.log('Injector does not have second service!');
    }

    if(common){
        common.action();
    }
    if(first){
        first.action();
    }
    if(second){
        second.action();
    }
}]);
```

*1.js:*

```
myApp.service('firstService', function(){
    this.action = function(){
        console.log('First service is loaded');
    }
});
```

*2.js:*

```
myApp.service('secondService', function(){
    this.action = function(){
        console.log('Second service is loaded');
    }
});
```

See it live in [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5y3et8Wm76tokCyuDtR0?p=catalogue)! Try to play with `<script>` tags and watch for console output.

P.S. And, as @Problematic said, you can use `$injector.has()`, starting from AngularJS 1.1.5.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i need. I'm using latest Angular, so use 'has'!

Answer (score 62):

Apparently not using automatic injection. However, you can inject the injector and check for the service:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', [
    '$scope', '$injector', 'firstRequiredService', 'secondRequiredService', 
    function ($scope, $injector, firstRequiredService, secondRequiredService) {
        if ($injector.has('firstOptionalService')) {
            var firstOptionalService = $injector.get('firstOptionalService');
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Cool! I want them backport `$injector.has` to 1.0.7!

Comment: I like this answer over @madhead's because it uses `$injector.has` instead of `try`/`catch`

Comment: @Problematic is there a way to use this to pass an optional variable to the controller?  I'm not looking to create a service but simply pass an optional boolean or object variable.  Is this possible?

Comment: @JeremyMoritz if I'm understanding what you're asking, you can't use it with arbitrary values, but you could register a constant or value provider, and use it in the same way as above.

Answer (score 14):

I'd probably go with @Proplematic's suggestion of using $injector. However, there is another solution I can think of: register all services with their default values (`null` for example) in your bootstrap file.  When additional files are loaded, later definitions will override the default definitions, somewhat creating the effect you desire.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.value("service1", null)
   .value("service2", null)
   .factory("service1", function() { return "hello"; });

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, service1, service2) {
  console.log(service1); // hello
  console.log(service2); // null
});
```

[Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8w5o8vqn3FFcSMv7FvWD?p=preview)

Comment: This is hacky, but works. I am using it where I have multiple routes that share a controller, but only a few need a resolve: {} property injected.

Comment: This is best answer for my project with optional parameters.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks!
I need to use the same controller as modal controller and as ng-controller too. And for modal controller I need additional resolvers.

Answer (score 10):

This is how i solved it:

```
var deps = [];

try {
    //Check if optionalModule is available
    angular.module('app').requires.push('optionalModule');
    deps.push('optionalModule');
} catch(e){
    console.log("Warn: module optionalModule not found. Maybe it's normal");
}

angular.module('app', deps).factory('stuff', function($injector) {
    var optionalService;

    if($injector.has('optionalService')) {
        optionalService = $injector.get('optionalService');
    } else {
        console.log('No waffles for you, dear sir');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this way..

```
try {
    angular.module('YourModule').requires.push('Optional dependency module');
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

'requires' is an Array of dependency modules.