# AngularJS: add dependencies to my app before bootstrap it

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dependencies

I am working with AngularJS from a short amount of time so I am still a kind of lost with it. Sorry if the question is trivial or was already asked... I have seen so many different questions / posts / docs that I am really confused.

This is the problem I am facing: I would like to dynamically add dependencies to my app (I am going to refer to it as rootApp), **before bootstrap it**.
At the moment the bootstrap happens manually: for what I have read on the web, should be possible to dynamically add dependencies to the app before bootstrap it (and that is why the bootstrap is happening manually).

I have different templates (powered by Template Toolkit) that can load different modules as dependency: for example, the template "myComponent" needs to load, as dependency, the Angular module myComponent; the template "myTable" needs to load, as dependency, the Angular module NGTable, etc...
What I would like to do is to define the module for the rootApp as:
`// NOTE: no dependencies as argument!`
`rootAppModule = angular.module('rootApp', []);`

and then add dependencies on demand, something like:

`rootAppModule.pushDependency( myComponentModule );`
`rootAppModule.pushDependency( NGTableModule );`

then finally bootstrap:
`angular.bootstrap(document, ['rootAppModule']);`

Someone can help me?

PS I have seen there are Angular plugins to load dependencies AFTER the bootstrap of the app but here I would be happy doing it before the bootstrap. It should be easier, so I would prefer to avoid (not needed?) complexity.

**edit:** 
I have found the array "requires", follows an example:
`angular.module("rootAppModule").requires.push("myComponentModule");`
from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542032/optional-dependencies-in-angularjs/)
Anybody can tell if that is a reliable solution?

Comment: But do you need specific dependencies for different controllers? In that case you could use the 'resolve' property in $routeProvider to load dependencies before loading the controller. Doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: I don't... I just need to specify dependencies (as "components" or "plugins") for the app itself before its bootstrapping. I don't understand why it shouldn't be the same easy as push an item (a dependency) in a list (the dependency list). (Thanks anyway)

Comment: maybe combining requirejs and angular would solve your problem. Have a look at https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed

Comment: Thanks @marcinn . Honestly that is the next step in my roadmap but, at the moment, I was thinking about something quicker, to just fill the dependencies of my app before the bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this was already in the "edit" but a friend told me that is good habit to answer own questions when there is an answer, so here it is:

I have found the array "requires", follows an example: `angular.module("rootAppModule").requires.push("myComponentModule");`
from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542032/optional-dependencies-in-angularjs/)

Anybody can tell if that is a reliable solution?
Thanks.