# Load module only if exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, firebase

Im developing app that will work only in corporate network which doesn't have internet and is hosted in IIS, asp.net mvc architec. In development stage i want to use some bugtrackers and tasks feature, which implemented with firebase, and in production mode i will disable firebase via bundle config (`if #debug or #release`). So in production mode im gonna disable firebase (would not load firebase script) Is there any workaround to load dependency only if it exists?
Looked at [Optional dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542032/optional-dependencies-in-angularjs) but i dont think that `try catch` is best way to go. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you replace the module with an empty module when in Production mode?

Comment: Try and catch is the best way. Or you could use the directory class and check for the file

Comment: Another workaround is to monkey patch `angular.module` and remember registered module yourself.

Comment: The best answer here would be to make this part of your build process. Short of that, try/catch is going to be your friend.

Comment: solved with bundle, made copy of app.js, and in release mode, i will use this one which doesnt include firebase deps `if #debug #release`.. not perfect, still waiting for elegant solution